# In pandas dataframe, generate third column data based on results in two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm a newbie to dataframes.  I have columns `A`, `B` and `C` and want to use the data in A and B to create a value in C.  For example, if `A = 1` and/or `B = 1`, then I want to place a `1` in column `C` and do this logic for all rows in the dataframe.

e.g. starting array:

```
         A  B  C
0        1  0  
1        0  1  
2        1  1  
3        0  0
```

etc

resulting array:

```
         A  B  C
0        1  0  1
1        0  1  1
2        1  1  1
3        0  0  0
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

Given a starting DF of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 1, 0], 'B': [0, 1, 1, 0]})
```

Then you can create column `C` as such:

```
df['C'] = (df == 1).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Then leaves `df` as:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  1
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  0  0  0
```

Comment: `df['C'] = (df == 1).any(axis=1).astype(int)` would suffice perhaps?

Comment: @JohnGalt yup - silly me - thank you. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['C'] = np.where(df.A | df.B, 1, 0)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  1  1  1

df['C'] = np.where((df.A == 0) & (df.B == 0), 0, 1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  1  1  1
```

Or simplier convert boolean `Series` to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['C'] = (df.A | df.B).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  1  1  1

df['C'] = (~((df.A == 0) & (df.B == 0))).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  1  1
2  1  0  1
3  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution using a `list comprehesion` and `zip`

```
df['C'] = [(1 if i or j == 1 else 0) for i,j in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

it returns:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  1
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  0  0  0
```

Change the condition if `'A'` and `'B'` `==` ***1*** use `&`:

Example:

```
df['C'] = [(1 if i & j == 1 else 0) for i,j in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

This will return:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  1  1  1
3  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(x):

    if (x.B==1) and (x.A !=1): #Or whatever logic you like
        return 1
    else: 
        return 0

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logical functions of numpy `logical_and` and `logical_or`

```
import numpy as np

df['C'] = np.logical_and(df['A'], df['B']).astype(int)
```